# Fail-fast behavior for Eureka client

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, microservices, netflix-eureka

It seems that [following problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61796189/configure-spring-boot-admin-server-with-fixed-list-of-registered-clients) doesn't have common decision and I try to solve it from another side. Microservices infrastructure consists of Spring Boot Microservices with Eureka-Zuul-Config-Admin Servers as service mesh. All Microservices runs inside Docker containers at the Kubernetes platform. Kubernetes monitors application health check (liveness/readyness probes) and redeploy it when health check in down state exceeds liveness probe timeout.

The problem is following - sometimes Microservice doesn't get correct Eureka server address after redeployment. Service discovery registration fails but Microservice continue working with health check `'UP'` and dependent Microservices miss it.

Microservices are interdependent and failure of one Microservice causes cascade failure of all dependent Microservices. I don't use Histrix because of some reasons and actually it is not resolve my problem - missed data from failed Microservice just disables entire functionality related to the set of dependent Microservices.

Question: Is it possible to configure something like `'fail-fast'` behavior for Eureka client without writing custom HealthIndicator? The actuator health check should be in `'DOWN'` state while Eureka client doesn't get `204` successful registration response from Eureka.

Here is an example of how I fix it in code. It has pretty simple behavior - healthcheck goes down 'forever' after exceeding timeout to successful registration in Eureka on start or/and during runtime. The main goal is that the Kubernetes will redeploy Microservice when liveness probe timeout exceeded.

```java
@Component
public class CustomHealthIndicator implements HealthIndicator {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomHealthIndicator.class);

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("eurekaClient")
    private EurekaClient eurekaClient;

    private static final int HEALTH_CHECK_DOWN_LIMIT_MIN = 15;

    private LocalDateTime healthCheckDownTimeLimit = getHealthCheckDownLimit();

    @Override
    public Health health() {
        int errCode = registeredInEureka();
        return errCode != 0
                ? Health.down().withDetail("Eureka registration fails", errCode).build()
                : Health.up().build();
    }

    private int registeredInEureka() {
        int status = 0;
        if (isStatusUp()) {
            healthCheckDownTimeLimit = getHealthCheckDownLimit();
        } else if (LocalDateTime.now().isAfter(healthCheckDownTimeLimit)) {
            logger.error("Exceeded {} min. limit for getting 'UP' state in Eureka", HEALTH_CHECK_DOWN_LIMIT_MIN);
            status = HttpStatus.GONE.value();
        }
        return status;
    }

    private boolean isStatusUp() {
        return eurekaClient.getInstanceRemoteStatus().compareTo(InstanceInfo.InstanceStatus.UP) == 0;
    }

    private LocalDateTime getHealthCheckDownLimit() {
        return LocalDateTime.now().plus(HEALTH_CHECK_DOWN_LIMIT_MIN, ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do the same by just configuring Spring components?